# Programmatically change the temperature of the display

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to programatically change the temperature of the entire display depending on time of day / ambient lighting conditions. Assume that I have a sensor that returns the ambient lighting conditions -- I would like to change the temperature of the display based on that. It's a bit like [flux](http://www.stereopsis.com/flux/). It will be a Windows box.

It would be great if I can interface with some Windows API if it exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you're talking about color temperature - not physical temperature :) See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063547/mfc-dim-main-window-when-showing-modal-dialog/4081552#4081552) for that. Basically you can make a transparent layered window (SetLayeredWindowAttributes) in the correct color (blue-ish for cold, red-ish for warm etc) that covers the entire screen.