# How do I dim or change the colour of a program that does not have focus?

Tags: windows, mfc

My users often open more than one instance of my program. They often have several undocked windows for each instance. This proves problematic when they want to switch between two instances (without using the Taskbar) because it's not always easy to see which window is from the instance in focus. They often click on the wrong window.

So, is there a way of dimming/tinting the windows from a program that I have control of (as in, I am the programmer) when it doesn't have focus?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MFC - dim main window when showing modal dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063547/mfc-dim-main-window-when-showing-modal-dialog)

Comment: You could handle the `WM_ACTIVATE/WM_ACTIVATEAPP` messages and then follow the link that Steve suggested which involves placing a translucent window over the top of the inactive windows.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, although I only want to affect the non-focused instance, not the current instance. I'll let you know how I get on. I'm sure you're all desperate to find out. :)